# LDAP error codes

Tags: php, authentication, ldap

Is there anybody who knows how to get whole LDAP error codes?

I'm using in PHP `ldap_error($ldapConn)` for code and `ldap_errno($ldapConn)` for name of the error. But `error 49 - LDAP_INVALID_CREDENTIALS` has 'suberrors' like 49/525, 49/530 etc. I need whole number of error but `ldap_error()` shows only 49 for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
ldap_get_option($ldapConn, LDAP_OPT_ERROR_STRING, $diagnosticMsg);
echo $diagnosticMsg;
```

Where `$diagnosticMsg` is then the full message that contains the extra information you're looking for.

In newer versions of PHP you can use `LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE` instead. That will contain the extended error code you're looking for. You can parse it doing something like this:

```
function getExtendedErrorNumber($diagnosticMsg) {
    $errorNumber = 0;

    if (!empty($diagnosticMsg)) {
        $errorNumber = explode(',', $diagnosticMsg);
        if (!isset($errorNumber[2])) {
            return 0;
        };
        $errorNumber = explode(' ', $errorNumber[2]);
        if (!isset($errorNumber[2])) {
            return 0;
        };
        $errorNumber = hexdec(intval($errorNumber[2]));
    }

    return $errorNumber;
}
```

Comment: What version of PHP I need for LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE? Server using 5.4.16.

Comment: Both of the constants are the same value in the end, so technically it shouldnt matter which you use. But you'll have to use the LDAP_OPT_ERROR_STRING with that PHP version. The other is only later versions of 5.6 and 7.0 I think.